# How to set selected value on a CFSelect and reload binded cfselects

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have in my application three CFSELECTS

```
<cfselect name    = "paisid" 
          id      = "paisid"
          display = "pais"
          value   = "codigo"
          bind    = "cfc:cidades.buscaPaises()"
          bindonload = "true" class="AE04"
/>

<cfselect name       = "estadoid"
          id         = "estadoid"
          display    = "snmestado"
          value      = "scdestado"
          bind       = "cfc:cidades.buscaEstados({paisid})"
          bindonload = "true"
          class      = "AE04"
/>

<cfselect name       = "cidadeid"
          id         = "cidadeid"
          display    = "snmcidade"
          value      = "snmcidade"
          bind       = "cfc:cidades.buscaCidades({estadoid})"
          bindonload = "true"
          class      = "AE04"
/>
```

i have in other part of the page this jquery:

```
$("#paisid").val('BR');
```

I need that, when `paisid` value is changed, the cfselects `estadoid` and `cidadeid` have to be reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#paisid").val('BR').trigger("change");
```

The problem is that setting a value on an input does not cause the associated event bindings to fire, and those event bindings are what drive the changing values to the child select boxes.  By manually triggering the change event after you set the value, those child select boxes will be notified of the event and operate as normal.

Comment: i think this don't gonna work... the binding is realized on load... i've tried with no success... but thanks anyway

Comment: Are you running that jQuery code within the document.ready handler?  If so, it should be fine.

Comment: the change of $("#paisid").val() is done in a onpagechangestart function of a formtowizard, so outside document.ready handler